# SelectedIndexChanged Event Firing Multiple Times

Tags: c#, datagridview

i need to perform an action when the user changes the value of an DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in my grid. Suppose i have to show a message.

the problem is that the messagebox.show("hello") code executes millions of times.

here's my code.

```
grilla.EditingControlShowing+=new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(grilla_EditingControlShowing);

void  grilla_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control is ComboBox) //i have only one combobox column.
            {
                ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)e.Control;
                // first remove event handler to keep from attaching multiple:
                cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);

                // now attach the event handler
                cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cb_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }

        }

        void cb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello");
        }
```

Comment: What language and platform is this?

Comment: Thank you.  Some languages look very similar to each other, and use the same terminology.  It's usually a good idea to include the language in the list of tags.

Comment: I also had HUGE ISSUE with the EXACT same logic as you (I guess we use same tutorials or code example...). What I did is to put my action on the click handler of the combobox: User change value and click on the combobx and then I do what I need to do. I was not able to correctly put the code in the SelectedIndexChanged, too much problem, null exception and so on. But i'm ready to learn (and correct my program!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally y found a code that does exactly what i wanted:

```
grid.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += (s, e) => 
            {
                if (grid.IsCurrentCellDirty)
                {
                    grid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

                    MessageBox.Show("hello");
                }
            };
```

The message show only one time after change the value of the comboboxcell.